# Fundamental rules of crawling a website

Tags: robots.txt, web-crawler

I am studying about website crawling.

I would like to ask following questions.

1. If a website appears in the result of google search, can I crawl the website?
2. In robots.txt of a website, the following is written. How can I confirm webpages which is prohibited crawling in this website, with browser?

   ```
    Disallow: /usr/top
   ```

Could you tell me the answer of the above questions?

Comment: Could you rephrase your second question? I don’t understand it. -- If it’s a separate question, you should probably create a new question for it.

Comment: Sorry. I edit the second question. Could you understand?

Comment: Do you want a way to easily see if the current web page (opened in your browser) is blocked in the robots.txt?  Or do you want to confirm that no bot crawled it? Or do you want to know what this `Disallow` means? Or …?

Comment: I want to know concrete webpage URLs indicated in /usr/top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If a website appears in the result of google search, can I crawl the website?

I assume that you want to honour robots.txt. In that case the answer is: **No**, not necessarily.

You have to check the robots.txt. It might be the case that Google’s bot is allowed to crawl it, but your bot is not allowed to.

> I want to know concrete webpage URLs indicated in `/usr/top`

When there is a line like `Disallow: /usr/top`, you can’t know which existing URLs are blocked by this. `Disallow` always takes the *beginning* of a URL path as value. So in this example, it would block the following URLs (assuming that the robots.txt is at `http://example.com/robots.txt`):

- `http://example.com/usr/top`
- `http://example.com/usr/top/`
- `http://example.com/usr/top.html`
- `http://example.com/usr/topfoo`
- `http://example.com/usr/top/foo/bar`
- `http://example.com/usr/top/foo/bar.html`
- …

Answer (score 0):

- If a website appears in the result of google search, can I crawl the website?

The short answer is *maybe*. The long answer is: many websites will have a terms of use/agreement or use that may mention if crawling it is allowed. For example, I believe FaceBook will not allow crawling.

In regards to the robots.txt file: [this link may be helpful](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6062608?hl=en).

Comment: If they don't want to be crawled they should know well enough by now to use robots.txt; there's no programmatic way to ensure the crawler can, or the crawler's author reasonably could, read the ToS.